# Spark 2.0 - How to obtain Cluster ID associated with Cluster Center

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

I want to know what is the ID associated with the Cluster Centers. `model.transform(dataset)` will assign a predicted cluster ID to my data points, and `model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)` will print these cluster centers, but I cannot figure out how to associate the cluster centers with their ID.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans

// Loads data.
val dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_kmeans_data.txt")

// Trains a k-means model.
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(dataset)
val prediction = model.transform(dataset)

// Shows the result.
println("Cluster Centers: ")
model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

Ideally, I want an output such as:

```
|I.D     |cluster center |
==========================
|0       |[0.0,...,0.3]  |
|2       |[1.0,...,1.3]  |
|1       |[2.0,...,1.3]  |
|3       |[3.0,...,1.3]  |
```

It does not seem to me that the println order is sorted by ID. I tried converting `model.clusterCenters` into a DF to `transform()` on it, but I couldn't figure out how to convert `Array[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]` to `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you saved the data it will write cluster_id and Cluster_center. You can read the file, can see the desired output

```
    model.save(sc, "/user/hadoop/kmeanModel")
    val parq = sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/hadoop/kmeanModel/data/*")
    parq.collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: @BéatriceMoissinac, we faced the issue, looked into source code and found it.